# t.test on bootstrapped estimates

Tags: r, bootstrap

Let's say I have a statistic (in this example `sd`) for sample `v1` and sample `v2`. I would like to compare those two statistics but since I have only two values I cannot run a test like `t.test`, so I thought I could create bootstrap estimates of `sd`:

```
v1 <- c(10,23,21,12,14,14,13,14,15,25)
v2 <- c(10,11,10,13,13,13,14,19,12,23)

bs1 <- replicate(1000,sd(sample(v1,10,replace=TRUE)))
bs2 <- replicate(1000,sd(sample(v2,10,replace=TRUE)))

t.test(bs1,bs2)
```

Would this be a valid approach? My feeling is that it isn't, since I can get really small p.values as the sample size is very large, but just want to make sure.

Comment: 1) What do the various variables in your code indicate? 2) What exactly do you have and want to test?

Comment: I don't understand how you can do bootstrap if you only have two estimates of the standard deviation and not the original samples. In your code, you have the original samples but before you claim you can't do a t-test because you don't have them? What is correct? Also, a t-test compares means and not standard deviations. For comparison of variances you use an F-test.

Comment: @Roland, sorry for the confusion. I actually have the original samples (v1 and v2) which are squared errors. Initially I thought I could compare the mean squared errors (mean.v1 vs mean.v2), which would give me the two estimates. Since I only have two means, I thought I should bootstrap to create a bunch of mean squared errors for v1 and v2 so that I can compare them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bootstrap is a valid approach, but the t-test is not valid.  One simple approach is to take the quantiles of the difference of the sample metrics and test whether that confidence interval includes 0.

Also, in this case, Levene's test for equality of variances is also available as an alternative.

````r
v1 <- c(10,23,21,12,14,14,13,14,15,25)
v2 <- c(10,11,10,13,13,13,14,19,12,23)

set.seed(10320)
bs1 <- replicate(1000, sd(sample(v1, 10, replace=TRUE)))
bs2 <- replicate(1000, sd(sample(v2, 10, replace=TRUE)))

# t.test(bs1,bs2) # Not correct

quantile(bs1 - bs2, prob = c(0.025, 0.975))

require(car)

car::leveneTest(c(v1, v2), factor(c(rep("v1", length(v1)), rep("v2", length(v2)))),
                center = mean)

```
````

Comment: @R Carnell, thanks for your answer! If I decide to use `mean` instead of `sd`, I could basically use the same bootstrapping code but replace `sd` with `mean`, is that right?

Comment: Yes.  You can replace `sd` with `mean`.  However, if you are testing the null hypothesis that the distribution means are equal, then you should consider the `t.test(v1, v2)` first.  If you have reason to believe that the distribution of `v1` or `v2` is so skewed that the mean of a random sample is not expected to be normally distributed, then you should switch to the bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem with this approach: It is incredibly sensitive to the number of bootstraps.  Suppose that the null is true (the population variances between the two samples really are equal).  I can still reject the null just by cranking up the number of bootstraps.  That doesn't really sound like a good approach.

```
set.seed(0)
v1 <- rnorm(10)
v2 <- rnorm(10)

bs1 <- replicate(1000,sd(sample(v1,10,replace=TRUE)))
bs2 <- replicate(1000,sd(sample(v2,10,replace=TRUE)))

t.test(bs1,bs2)
```

What I suspect you're trying to do is use the bootstrap to test the hypothesis that the two variances are the same.  That can be done as follows:

```
set.seed(0)
v1 <- c(10,23,21,12,14,14,13,14,15,25)
v2 <- c(10,11,10,13,13,13,14,19,12,23)

bootstraps <- replicate(10000,{
  v1b <- sample(v1, replace = T)
  v2b <- sample(v2, replace = T)
  
  log(var(v1b)) - log(var(v2b))
})
```

Here, I've computed the difference of the two variances on the log scale so if the resulting bootstrap confidence interval contains 0, then we know the ratio of these variances is consistent with a value of 1 (i.e. that the data are consistent with the same population variance)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I was looking for a way to test whether the variances of v1 and v2 are equivalent. `if the resulting bootstrap confidence interval contains 0`, you mean I should compute the confidence interval for bootstraps like `confint(lm(bootstraps~1))` and if it contains 0 I should conclude the variances are the same, is that correct?

Comment: @locus no, that isn’t how to compute the bootstrap CI. You treat the bootstraps as if they were samples from the sampling distribution. Just compute appropriate quantiles

Comment: Ah ok, so `quantile(bootstraps, prob=c(0.025,0.975))` like in R Carnell's answer?

Comment: @locus Yes that is correct